# Using the argument principle to compute the number of zeroes of $z^4-z^3+3z^2+1$ in the $B_1(0)$

Tags: complex-analysis

Find the number of zeroes of $p(z)=z^4-z^3+3z^2+1$ that lie inside $B_1(0)=${$z\in \mathbb{C} : |z|<1$}.
My first thought was to use the argument principle so that to find the number of zeroes, it suffices to compute $\displaystyle{\frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{\partial B_1(0)} \frac{f’}{f}(z) dz }$

However I’m not sure how to proceed? It doesn’t seem like the residue theorem will be helpful to me here, as it seems like you need to know the zeroes of the function in order to use the residue theorem to begin with

Comment: @user8675309 I haven’t heard of Rouche’s Theorem, but that link was immensely helpful thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution via Rouche and Hurwitz.

with $D$ being the open unit disc, write
$p(z)=z^4-z^3+3z^2+1=(z-\lambda_1)(z-\lambda_2)(z-\lambda_3)(z-\lambda_4)$

**(1.)** $p$ has no roots in the unit circle, $\partial D$
$p(1)=4$ and $p(-1)=6$ so any roots of unity are non-real, coming in conjugate pairs.  But the product of all roots is $1$ hence there can only be roots in the unit circle if $\big\{\lambda_1, \lambda_2, \lambda_3, \lambda_4\big\}\subseteq \partial D$, where $\lambda_2 = \bar \lambda_1$ and $\lambda_4=\bar \lambda_3$.  Then matching coefficients: first looking at $z^3$ we have $1=\lambda_1 + \lambda_2 + \lambda_3 + \lambda_4 $ and then looking at $z$ we have $0=(\lambda_1\lambda_2)\lambda_3+(\lambda_1\lambda_2)\lambda_4+\lambda_1(\lambda_3\lambda_4)+\lambda_2(\lambda_3\lambda_4) =  \lambda_3 +  \lambda_4+\lambda_1+\lambda_2=1$ which is impossible. Conclude $p$ has no roots in the unit circle.

*alternative to coefficient matching:* consider $p'(z)= z \big(4z^2 -3z +6\big)$ and use the quadratic formula to conclude $p'(z)$ has roots with modulus $\gt 1$ hence $p(z)$ must as well (Gauss-Lucas)

**(2.)** $p$ has exactly two roots in $D$
$p_k(z) := \frac{k}{1+k}z^4-z^3+3z^2+1$ for $k\in \mathbb N$
for $z\in \partial D$ we have
$\big \vert 3z^2\big\vert = 3\gt \frac{k}{1+k} + 2 =\frac{k}{1+k}\big \vert z\big \vert^4+ \big \vert -z\big \vert^3 + 1 \geq \big \vert \frac{k}{1+k}z^4-z^3+1\big \vert$
$\implies 3z^2$ and $p_k(z)$ have the same number of roots in $D$ per Rouche, i.e. $p_k(z)$ has exactly 2 roots in $D$ for all $k$.  Finally $p_k(z)$ and $p(z)$ have the same number of roots in $D$ for $k$ large enough (Hurwitz), i.e. $p(z)$ has exactly two roots in $D$.

Answer (score 1):

A precalculus-level solution . . .

First consider real roots.

If $z < 0$ then
$$
p(z) = -z^3+(z^4+3z^2+1) > -z^3 > 0
$$
so $p$ has no negative real roots.

Noting that 
$$
p'(z)=z(4z^2-3z+6)=z\left(\Bigl(2z-\frac{3}{4}\Bigr)^2+\frac{87}{16}\right)
$$
we get that $p'(z) > 0$ for all $z > 0$.

Thus $p$ is strictly increasing on the interval $(0,\infty)$, hence since $p(0)=1$, 
it follows that $p(z)\ge 1$ for all $z\ge 0$, so $p$ has no nonnegative real roots.

Hence $p$ has no real roots.

Since $p$ has real coefficients, the non-real roots of $p$ occur in 
complex conjugate pairs.

Thus we can write the roots of $p$ as
$
s_1,s_2,s_3,s_4=r_1,\overline{r_1},r_2,\overline{r_2}
$.

By Vieta's formulas we have $s_1s_2s_3s_4=1$, hence $|r_1|{\,\cdot\,}|r_2|=1$.

Without loss of generality, assume $|r_1|\le|r_2|$.

Suppose $|r_1|=|r_2|$.

Then $|r_1|=1$ and $|r_2|=1$, hence
$\overline{r_1}={\large{\frac{1}{r_1}}}$
and
$\overline{r_2}={\large{\frac{1}{r_2}}}$.

It follows that
$$
s_1+s_2+s_3+s_4
=
\frac{1}{s_1}+\frac{1}{s_2}+\frac{1}{s_3}+\frac{1}{s_4}
$$
But by Vieta's formulas
$$
s_1+s_2+s_3+s_4=1
$$
whereas
$$
\frac{1}{s_1}+\frac{1}{s_2}+\frac{1}{s_3}+\frac{1}{s_4}
=
s_2s_3s_4
+
s_1s_3s_4
+
s_1s_2s_4
+
s_1s_2s_3
=
0
$$
hence $|r_1|\ne|r_2|$.

Then $|r_1| < |r_2|$, hence from $|r_1|{\,\cdot\,}|r_2|=1$, we get
$|r_1| < 1$
and
$|r_2| > 1$.

Finally, since
$|\overline{r_1}|=|r_1|$
and
$|\overline{r_2}|=|r_2|$,
it follows that $p$ has exactly two roots in $B_1(0)$.